# KIBANA - WAZUH pattern index

Tags: indexing, design-patterns, kibana, field, wazuh

I have a project to install wazuh as FIM on linux, AIX and windows.
I managed to install Manager and all agents on all systems and I can see all three connected on the Kibana web as agents.

I created test file on the linux agent and I can find it also on web interface, so servers are connected.
[Here is test file found in wazuh inventory tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFCqo.png)

But, I am not recieving any logs if I modify this test file.

This is my settings in ossec.conf under syscheck on agent server>

```
<directories>/var/ossec/etc/test</directories>
<directories report_changes="yes" check_all="yes" realtime="yes">/var/ossec/etc/test</directories>
```

**And now I ma also strugling to understand meanings of index patterns, index templates and fields.
I dont understand what they are and why we need to set it.**

My settings on manager server - /usr/share/kibana/data/wazuh/config/wazuh.yml

```
alerts.sample.prefix: 'wazuh-alerts-*'
pattern: 'wazuh-alerts-*'
```

On the kibana web I also have this error when I am trying to check ,,events,, -the are no logs in the events.

```
Error: The field "timestamp" associated with this object no longer exists in the index pattern. Please use another field.
    at FieldParamType.config.write.write (http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/data/kibana/data.plugin.js:1:627309)
    at http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/data/kibana/data.plugin.js:1:455052
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at writeParams (http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/data/kibana/data.plugin.js:1:455018)
    at AggConfig.write (http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/data/kibana/data.plugin.js:1:355081)
    at AggConfig.toDsl (http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/data/kibana/data.plugin.js:1:355960)
    at http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/data/kibana/data.plugin.js:1:190748
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at agg_configs_AggConfigs.toDsl (http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/data/kibana/data.plugin.js:1:189329)
    at http://MYIP:5601/42959/bundles/plugin/wazuh/4.2.5-4206-1/wazuh.chunk.6.js:55:1397640
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**About FIM:**

here you can find the FIM documentation in case you don't have it:
https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/capabilities/file-integrity/fim-configuration.html
https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/reference/ossec-conf/syscheck.html.

The first requirement for this to work would be to ensure a FIM alert is triggered, could you check the alerts.json file on your manager? It is usually located under /var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json  In order to test this fully I would run "tail -f /var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json" and  make a change in yout directory , if no alerts is generated, then we will need to check the agent configuration.

**About indexing:**

Here you can find some documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-index-patterns.html#scripted-fields
https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/kibana-app/reference/elasticsearch.html

Regarding your error, The best way to solve this is to delete the index. To do this:
got to  `Kibana -> Stack management -> index patterns and there delete  wazuh-alerts-*.`
Then if you enter to Wazuh App the health check will create it again or you can follow this to create your index:
Go to `kibana -> stack management -> index pattern and select Create index pattern.`

Hope this information helps you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.

I managed to step over this issue, but I hit another error.

When I check `tail -f /var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json` I got never ending updating, thousands lines with errors like.

> {"timestamp":"2022-01-31T12:40:08.458+0100","rule":{"level":5,"description":"Systemd: Service has entered a failed state, and likely has not started.","id":"40703","firedtimes":7420,"mail":false,"groups":["local","systemd"],"gpg13":["4.3"],"gdpr":["IV_35.7.d"]},"agent":{"id":"003","name":"MYAGENTSERVERNAME","ip":"X.X.X.X"},"manager":{"name":"MYMANAGERSERVERNAME"},"id":"1643629208.66501653","full_log":"Jan 31 12:40:07 MYAGENTSERVERNAME systemd: Unit rbro-cbs-adapter-int.service entered failed state.","predecoder":{"program_name":"systemd","timestamp":"Jan 31 12:40:07","hostname":"MYAGENTSERVERNAME"},"decoder":{"name":"systemd"},"location":"/var/log/messages"}

But, I can also find alert if I change monitored file. (file> wazuhtest)

> {"timestamp":"2022-01-31T12:45:59.874+0100","rule":{"level":7,"description":"Integrity checksum changed.","id":"550","mitre":{"id":["T1492"],"tactic":["Impact"],"technique":["Stored Data Manipulation"]},"firedtimes":1,"mail":false,"groups":["ossec","syscheck","syscheck_entry_modified","syscheck_file"],"pci_dss":["11.5"],"gpg13":["4.11"],"gdpr":["II_5.1.f"],"hipaa":["164.312.c.1","164.312.c.2"],"nist_800_53":["SI.7"],"tsc":["PI1.4","PI1.5","CC6.1","CC6.8","CC7.2","CC7.3"]},"agent":{"id":"003","name":"MYAGENTSERVERNAME","ip":"x.x.xx.x"},"manager":{"name":"MYMANAGERSERVERNAME"},"id":"1643629559.67086751","full_log":"File '/var/ossec/etc/wazuhtest' modified\nMode: realtime\nChanged attributes: size,mtime,inode,md5,sha1,sha256\nSize changed from '61' to '66'\nOld modification time was: '1643618571', now it is '1643629559'\nOld inode was: '786558', now it is '786559'\nOld md5sum was: '2dd5fe4d08e7c58dfdba76e55430ba57'\nNew md5sum is : 'd8b218e9ea8e2da8e8ade8498d06cba8'\nOld sha1sum was: 'ca9bac5a2d8e6df4aa9772b8485945a9f004a2e3'\nNew sha1sum is : 'bd8b8b5c20abfe08841aa4f5aaa1e72f54a46d31'\nOld sha256sum was: '589e6f3d691a563e5111e0362de0ae454aea52b7f63014cafbe07825a1681320'\nNew sha256sum is : '7f26a582157830b1a725a059743e6d4d9253e5f98c52d33863bc7c00cca827c7'\n","syscheck":{"path":"/var/ossec/etc/wazuhtest","mode":"realtime","size_before":"61","size_after":"66","perm_after":"rw-r-----","uid_after":"0","gid_after":"0","md5_before":"2dd5fe4d08e7c58dfdba76e55430ba57","md5_after":"d8b218e9ea8e2da8e8ade8498d06cba8","sha1_before":"ca9bac5a2d8e6df4aa9772b8485945a9f004a2e3","sha1_after":"bd8b8b5c20abfe08841aa4f5aaa1e72f54a46d31","sha256_before":"589e6f3d691a563e5111e0362de0ae454aea52b7f63014cafbe07825a1681320","sha256_after":"7f26a582157830b1a725a059743e6d4d9253e5f98c52d33863bc7c00cca827c7","uname_after":"root","gname_after":"root","mtime_before":"2022-01-31T09:42:51","mtime_after":"2022-01-31T12:45:59","inode_before":786558,"inode_after":786559,"diff":"1c1\n< dadadadadad\n---\n> dfsdfdadadadadad\n","changed_attributes":["size","mtime","inode","md5","sha1","sha256"],"event":"modified"},"decoder":{"name":"syscheck_integrity_changed"},"location":"syscheck"}
> {"timestamp":"2022-01-31T12:46:08.452+0100","rule":{"level":3,"description":"Log file rotated.","id":"591","firedtimes":5,"mail":false,"groups":["ossec"],"pci_dss":["10.5.2","10.5.5"],"gpg13":["10.1"],"gdpr":["II_5.1.f","IV_35.7.d"],"hipaa":["164.312.b"],"nist_800_53":["AU.9"],"tsc":["CC6.1","CC7.2","CC7.3","PI1.4","PI1.5","CC7.1","CC8.1"]},"agent":{"id":"003","name":"MYAGENTSERVERNAME","ip":"x.x.xx.x"},"manager":{"name":"MYMANAGERSERVERNAME"},"id":"1643629568.67099280","full_log":"ossec: File rotated (inode changed): '/var/ossec/etc/wazuhtest'.","decoder":{"name":"ossec"},"location":"wazuh-logcollector"}

Also I can see this alert in messages logs on the manager server>

> Jan 31 12:46:10 MYMANAGERSERVERNAME filebeat[186670]: 2022-01-31T12:46:10.379+0100#011WARN#011[elasticsearch]#011elasticsearch/client.go:405#011Cannot index event publisher.Event{Content:beat.Event{Timestamp:time.Time{wall:0xc07610e0563729bf, ext:10888984451164, loc:(*time.Location)(0x55958e3622a0)}, Meta:{"pipeline":"filebeat-7.14.0-wazuh-alerts-pipeline"}, Fields:{"agent":{"ephemeral_id":"dd9ff0c5-d5a9-4a0e-b1b3-0e9d7e8997ad","hostname":"MYMANAGERSERVERNAME","id":"03fb57ca-9940-4886-9e6e-a3b3e635cd35","name":"MYMANAGERSERVERNAME","type":"filebeat","version":"7.14.0"},"ecs":{"version":"1.10.0"},"event":{"dataset":"wazuh.alerts","module":"wazuh"},"fields":{"index_prefix":"wazuh-alerts-4.x-"},"fileset":{"name":"alerts"},"host":{"name":"MYMANAGERSERVERNAME"},"input":{"type":"log"},"log":{"file":{"path":"/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json"},"offset":127261462},"message":"{"timestamp":"2022-01-31T12:46:08.452+0100","rule":{"level":3,"description":"Log file rotated.","id":"591","firedtimes":5,"mail":false,"groups":["ossec"],"pci_dss":["10.5.2","10.5.5"],"gpg13":["10.1"],"gdpr":["II_5.1.f","IV_35.7.d"],"hipaa":["164.312.b"],"nist_800_53":["AU.9"],"tsc":["CC6.1","CC7.2","CC7.3","PI1.4","PI1.5","CC7.1","CC8.1"]},"agent":{"id":"003","name":"xlcppt36","ip":"10.74.96.34"},"manager":{"name":"MYMANAGERSERVERNAME"},"id":"1643629568.67099280","full_log":"ossec: File rotated (inode changed): '/var/ossec/etc/wazuhtest'.","decoder":{"name":"ossec"},"location":"wazuh-logcollector"}","service":{"type":"wazuh"}}, Private:file.State{Id:"native::706-64776", PrevId:"", Finished:false, Fileinfo:(*os.fileStat)(0xc00095ea90), Source:"/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json", Offset:127262058, Timestamp:time.Time{wall:0xc076063e1f1b1286, ext:133605185, loc:(*time.Location)(0x55958e3622a0)}, TTL:-1, Type:"log", Meta:map[string]string(nil), FileStateOS:file.StateOS{Inode:0x2c2, Device:0xfd08}, IdentifierName:"native"}, TimeSeries:false}, Flags:0x1, Cache:publisher.EventCache{m:common.MapStr(nil)}} (status=400): {"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"data_stream [<wazuh-alerts-4.x-{2022.01.31||/d{yyyy.MM.dd|UTC}}>] must not contain the following characters [ , ", *, \, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]"}

Here is output form apps check.

```
curl "http://localhost:9200"
{

  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.14.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "6bc13727ce758c0e943c3c21653b3da82f627f75",
    "build_date" : "2021-09-15T10:18:09.722761972Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

filebeat test output

> elasticsearch: http://127.0.0.1:9200...
> parse url... OK
> connection...
> parse host... OK
> dns lookup... OK
> addresses: 127.0.0.1
> dial up... OK
> TLS... WARN secure connection disabled
> talk to server... OK
> version: 7.14.2

So .. I can see alerts coming from Agent, but Its not reaching Kibana yet. On the kibana web I can see agent active and connected.